# winapi: how to prevent WM_DROPFILES processing OLE IDropSource from application itself?

Tags: winapi, drag-and-drop, ole

I have an application written to process files dropping using WM_DROPFILES. And later I decided to add an OLE IDropSource to application so users can DnD an icon to other applications to open that opened file in other applications.

And I want to prevent users DnDing that icon on same window (to prevent file opening accidentally), any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand, but if you own the source and destination, you can add any private information to an IDataObject so, if you drag from one of your windows and drop to one of your windows, you can detect it's all yours and handle it appropriately.

Comment: @SimonMourier but the drop target here handles HDROP with `DragQueryFile` and not a full version of IDropTarget. (i.e. there is no IDropTarget for the window) and how can I get private member from standard HDROP?

Comment: DragQueryFile is a high level helper that is limited to the old CF_DROP format (HDROP points to DROPFILES I think, there's nothing super interesting here). Implementing IDropTarget would give you more control.

Comment: @Roy What you are asking for is simply not possible with `WM_DROPFILES`, you will have to change your code to implement `IDropTarget` and use `RegisterDragDrop()` instead. Only then will your drop handler have access to the `IDataObject` that is being dragged, and can thus query it for whatever private data you choose to put in it to identify yourself to your handler

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments, I decided to add extra fields(i.e. my window's handle number) after file list (and 2 NULL end-of-list markers), and handle it before calling `DragQueryFile`.

Related commit in particular: https://github.com/roytam1/rtoss/commit/ee75ece1d334bd20c863cfd35424096247de633c